# ionic 4 ng-true-value equivalence

Tags: ionic4

I'm rewriting an ionic 1 app to ionic 4.5.0, and i have a calculator like this in ionic 1:

HTML:

```
    <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-positive" id="myid" ng-model="data.product1" ng-false-value="0" ng-true-value="50">{{data.product1}}
      <i class="icon ion-social-euro"></i>
    </ion-toggle>
```

ControllerJs:

```
$scope.data = {
    'product1' : 0,
    'product2' : 0,
    'product3' : 0
}
```

On ionic 1 we had directives like:

> ng-false-value="0" ng-true-value="50"

so, when toggle were on, the true value were 50, and false 0.

On my new app, i'm trying to do the same:

HTML:

```
   <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Product 1 {{data.product1}}</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle name="product1" [(ngModel)]="data.product1"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

ts

```
data: any = { 
    product1: 0, 
    product2: 0,
    product3: 0
};
```

> {{data.product1}} is showing 0, but when i activate the toggle it's showing true or false

I have found this solution, but it's for angular: https://juristr.com/blog/2018/02/ng-true-value-directive/

Is there any equivalent or something else for ng-true-value and ng-false-value in ionic 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct approach is:

HTML:

```
 <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Product1 {{data.product1}}</ion-label>
          <ion-toggle name="product1" [(ngModel)]="data.product1" (ionChange)="calculateProduct1()"></ion-toggle>
 </ion-item>
```

.ts

```
data: any = {
  product1: 0,
  product2: 0
}

calculateProduct1() {
  if (this.data.product1) {   // toggle is true
    this.data.product1 = 50;
  } else {                         // toggle is false    
    this.data.product1 = 0;
  }
}
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934484/tomas-vancoillie

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `ionChange` event to add/subtract 50 when the toggle changes value.

In this example we are passing the product key of the data object, and the toggled value. This way you can reuse the function.

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Product 1 {{data.product1}}</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle name="product1" [(ngModel)]="toggle.product1" (ionChange)="toggleValues('product1', 50)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

```js
toggle = {
  'product1': false;
  // add more
}

toggle50Values(productKey: string, value: number) {
  if (this.toggle[productKey]) {   // toggle is true
    this.data[productKey] += value;
  } else {                         // toggle is false    
    this.data[productName] -= value;
  }
}
```

Documentation: [Ion-toggle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toggle#events)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Anyways, it's not the best idea doing in this way cause i have a lot of toggles, for example, about 30, 40 witch i will sum and send by email as price quote request.

Comment: This is just an example. You can pass the value to add or subtract as an argument to fix that issue.

Comment: I just tested it again and it shows true and false, not 50 or 0.

Comment: I understand, I think the problem is in passing the argument in ionChange. We should pass a string like so: `(ionChange)="toggle50Values('product1', toggleProduct1)"`. I've updated my answer

Comment: What do you mean with productKey and productName?

Comment: Now I've made it more generic. toggleValues takes a first argument, which is the key from your data object and also the key from your toggle object. You can speficy the value as the second argument. When the toggle is change, it looks for in the toggle object to see if it is true or false, then it looks in your data object to add or substract accordingly.

Comment: It's not working either... What do you mean with productKey and productName?

Comment: I just edited, it's working, but with some adjustments, your initial code had unnecessary things like ('product1', toggleProduct1) or productKey and productName.

Comment: Yes and no. You can use the function for every product you have in the data object and for every different value like you stated before (50 - 40 - 30). But good that it's fixed ;)